# When using Storm in our application, Japanese characters are messed up in worker logs

Tags: clojure, apache-storm

When using Storm in our application, Japanese characters are messed up in worker logs. 
Are there any settings required in config file or elsewhere to support Japanese characters?

All we can see is multiple question marks "?" in place of Japanese characters.

Comment: What is your OS and what are the encoding settings for the worker logs?

Comment: Are you sure it's a problem with Storm and not whatever you are viewing the logs in?

Comment: @SpaceTrucker : OS is GNU/Linux and Ihave tried keeping UTF-8 encoding  for worker logs explicitly in the storm config file, still the issue persists.

Comment: @JeremyWall: Yes I have verified , issue is  not with the log files, where we are viewing the logs.

Comment: You can check Storm source code and check whether FileAppender is using UTF-8 encoding (assuming they are using that, I have no idea). Have you considered using rōmaji ?